# RecyclerView Bitmap not show all Bitmap Images

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-recyclerview

**RecyclerView Bitmap not show all Bitmap Images just show One on last but text show on every item**

**Here is my Adapter Code that I am using in my project:**

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList;
PathModel pathModel=pathList.get(position);
 holder.videoName= (TextView) myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);

holder.videoThumb= (CircularImageView) 
myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.VideoThumbnail);
holder.videoName.setText(pathModel.getPath());

holder.videoThumb.setImageBitmap(bitmapArrayList.get(position));
VideoAdapter videoAdapter=new VideoAdapter(this,pathList,bitmapArrayList);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
```

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMhj2.png)

**Updated Code is here of my Adapter **

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.ViewHolder>{
Context context;

ArrayList<PathModel> pathList;

View myLayoutView;

Bitmap bmThumbnail;

ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList;


public VideoAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<PathModel> pathList, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList) {

    this.context = context;

    this.pathList=pathList;

    this.bitmapArrayList=bitmapArrayList;
    }  
@Override

public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    myLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video_list, 
null);

    return new ViewHolder(myLayoutView);

    }
 @Override

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder myHolder,final int position) {

final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder ) myHolder;

PathModel pathModel=pathList.get(position);  

holder.videoName= (TextView) myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);

holder.videoThumb= (CircularImageView) 
myLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.VideoThumbnail);

holder.videoName.setText(pathModel.getPath());

holder.videoThumb.setImageBitmap(bitmapArrayList.get(position));

//    holder.videoThumb.setImageDrawable(new 
BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),bitmapArrayList.get(position)));
//    holder.videoThumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.ab_add_student);
   //    

holder.videoThumb.setImageURI(Uri.parse(pathList.get(position).getPath()));

   }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.pathList.size();
    }
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView videoName;

CircularImageView videoThumb;

ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
}
}
}
```

Comment: please check your bitmapArrayList doe's have a image or not ,' go with http://square.github.io/picasso/ to display images ,

Answer (score 1):

Image loading is a heavy task in android, So it is not good to load images in main thread and better to use external library like Picasso or gild for this.

Refer link:https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Don't forget to check the image path is null or not :)

Comment: I have tried Glide library but It also show last image and I am sure that the bitmap array is not null.
I will be happy If anyone provide me good solution

Comment: Yes please
Let me post

Comment: Here is the link of file please see it and advice me I am really worries. Thanks    https://ufile.io/hvm6b

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't download the file. Could you please update the code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should perform findViewById inside your `ViewHolder` instead

Comment: but why It show all text why not show just Bitmap images?